# Smooth shade icosphere created by geometry node

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes

I am setting up a cell for medical visualisaztion with parameters on the outside of the node group so people can change things and re-use the asset in various animations.

Now I have a very basic problem I can't seem to figure out. I created an icosphere using geometry nodes. When I right click and select "Smooth Shade" the icosphere does not smooth shade.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think the regular *Shade Smooth* command works on geometry created by Geometry Nodes unfortunately.

Currently, you will have to connect your ico sphere node to an *Attribute Fill* node. Set the node's second option to *Boolean* and set the *Attribute* to `shade_smooth`, then you'll be able to click the box next to *Value* to toggle between *Smooth* and *Flat* shading.

[image: Shade_smooth]